# Why is java telling me to return type int when I want type double to be returned

Tags: java, int, double

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOIIj.png)

in my code I want a double to be returned but instead, java says type int must be returned and I'm not sure why this is when in this method I use doubles.

Comment: Please post your code and message in text here, not as an image.

Comment: Add your method code please :)

Comment: you should return integer value instead double.

Comment: If you want to return `double`, change `public static int` --> `public static double`.

Answer (score 1):

Your return value must be the same as method type - public static int nameMethod must returning int value. If you want to return double - change type of method. To return double it should look like this

```
public static double nameMethod(){
//code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per you image attached,

`Double centimeters= .......
return centrimeters //this is where your code is failing`

As your method signature is of return type `int` and inside that you are calculating result in `double and returning the same`.Hence the issue.

Change either the calculation part `Double centimeters` to `int centimeters` or change the method signature to `double`.

Also post your code in `SO` dont attach images , as its really difficult for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You declare the return type of `calculateScore` method should be `int`, but you are trying to return a `Double` instead, which may cause it losing accuracy.

You should

- Declare the method as `double calculateScore()`

or return the `intValue` of `Double`

- `return centimerters.intValue()`

Answer (score 1):

If you declare in a method that it will return a specific type, then later in the return statement the value that you are returning must be of the same type as the type declared in the method declaration **or** it must be of the type that inherits from the type in the method declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Change return type from `int` to `double` in method signature:

```
public static double calcFeetAndInchesToCentimeters(double feet, double inches) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 36 replace `int` by `double` in your signature method.